# Lotus Notes toolbar button to move documents to favorite folders

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I'm looking for assistance to create some Notes toolbar buttons to move selected documents to a favorite folders.  I just want to hardcode a specified folder per button.

I'm not familiar with Notes Formula language or creating buttons so any tips would be helpful.

thanks.

Comment: Is this for the email application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently learned how to do this myself so I could create two different buttons with hardcoded folder locations.  I used the following:

```
@Command([FolderDocuments];"Foldername";"1")
```

Of course, replace "Foldername" with the name you need and be sure to leave in the quotes.

Where it got a little tricky for me was trying to move an email to a subfolder of a folder.  The normal backslash didn't seem to work.  I don't know what made me think of it, but I tried two backslashes and that worked fine.

```
@Command([FolderDocuments];"Foldername\\subfolder";"1")
```

I know you're looking to hardcode the buttons, but if you're looking to create more than 2-3 buttons, I'd suggest looking to use a simple popup that lets you choose from a list of choices.  That way you don't have to memorize which button is which and you won't run out of room on your toolbar.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 2):

@Command([Folder]; "folderName") will copy the selected document to "foldername"

Create Action on the view you wish to copy documents from and drop the above code in. You can play around with the Actions properties to control appearance, location etc.

Comment: Thanks.  However, I would like to MOVE the file not COPY.  Is there a formula for the MOVE operation?

Answer (score 2):

Use a formula [like this](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/6b70b5ac6c5bd9cb85256c54004c253c?OpenDocument)

`@Command( [Folder] ; folderName ; moveOrCopy )`

The following formula will move the selected document to the folder named "My Favorite":

`@Command( [Folder] ; "My Favorite" ; "1")`

If you omit `folderName` the Move To Folder dialog will be displayed.

The `moveOrCopy` parameter is optional.  A value of "1" moves the document to the folder. A value of "0" copies the document to the folder. If you omit this parameter, Folder assumes a value of "0" (copy).

Also, if you have a subfolder, you can specify it with a double backslash like this:

`@Command( [Folder] ; "My Favorite\\My Subfolder" ; "1")`

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on a lot of factors that you've not specified here.

Is this for the Notes client?  For a single database?  Is the objective a personal favorites list for each user, or a shared favorites list? If yes for all of these, then why do you want to use a toolbar button for this?  Just set up a 'Favorites' folder in the application, mark it as 'Shared, personal on first use', and teach users to move selected documents to it via drag and drop.

If it's for web browser users but still for a single database, drag and drop won't work so OTTA's answer is correct.

But if what you are trying to do is create a unified 'Favorites' feature that spans multiple databases, whether it's personal or otherwise... there's considerably more programming to do.

Comment: It's actually very simple I think.  Just a simple couple of buttons to help me put emails into some email folders once I've checked them.

Comment: I have to comment under my own answer because for some reason I'm not allowed to comment under OTTA's anser.  The full syntax is @Command( [Folder] ; folderName ; moveOrCopy).  Specify a value of "1" for the final argument if you want it moved, or specify "0" if you want it copied.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to take a look at SwiftFile, which learns from your behaviour and suggest folders to sort into. SwiftFile comes "for free" with your Notes Licence & Install SW.
http://www.research.ibm.com/swiftfile/

Comment: Thanks - looks like an interesting tool.  However it seems more focused on automated mail sorting - like notes rules - rather than the manual sorting I am trying to simplify.